# Show the count of inner array values in the following example

Tags: php

I have the following array i want to show the count of inner array values Please help me out.

```
Array
(
    [e1549b20-4cad-11e6-85b4-73d5cb14d4fe] => Array
        (
            [a029e160-4337-11e6-8db4-ad7de57838b4] => Array
                (
                    [0] => b46b70a2-481a-11e6-8b19-00262d644487
                    [1] => b4696a1e-481a-11e6-8b19-00262d644487
                )

            [40eca780-48ef-11e6-8a04-eb9fe0a25fc5] => Array
                (
                    [0] => b46b70a2-481a-11e6-8b19-00262d644487
                    [1] => b4696a1e-481a-11e6-8b19-00262d644487
                )

            [e5926390-44cf-11e6-bc85-19a184fbd10f] => Array
                (
                    [0] => b4696a1e-481a-11e6-8b19-00262d644487
                )

            [51a44c00-4a53-11e6-81fe-313fe319f95b] => Array
                (
                    [0] => b4696a1e-481a-11e6-8b19-00262d644487
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: what you mean with count? how many array are inside the first one?

Comment: Could you paste what exacly you want in response? I cant understood what you want.

Comment: count the
 [40eca780-48ef-11e6-8a04-eb9fe0a25fc5] => Array
            (
                [0] => b46b70a2-481a-11e6-8b19-00262d644487
                [1] => b4696a1e-481a-11e6-8b19-00262d644487
            )

Comment: do you want to show the count for each nested array values or the total count of values?

Comment: yes i have to show the total count

[40eca780-48ef-11e6-8a04-eb9fe0a25fc5] => Array
            (
                [0] => b46b70a2-481a-11e6-8b19-00262d644487
                [1] => b4696a1e-481a-11e6-8b19-00262d644487
            )
like this
[40eca780-48ef-11e6-8a04-eb9fe0a25fc5] => Array
            (
              2
            )

Comment: Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Please Try with this functionality :

```
function getCount($arr, $count = 0) {
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        $count = getCount($value, $count);
    } else {
        $count = $count + 1;
    }
}
return $count;
```

}

echo getCount($arr);